# Python error that is workstation specific when running script

Tags: python, memory, traceback

I am getting an error on one workstation when running a Python script. The script runs fine on VMs and my workstation.

- `pip list` Shows packages are the same
- Workstations are all using Python 3.10.4 64bit
- This is the only workstation throwing this error.

It might be a memory issue, but the workstation has 2x4Gb RAM. I tried to chunk it out, but that did not work either. The file is barely 1Mb.

As troubleshooting, I cut the file to just 500 rows, and it ran fine. When I tried 1000 rows out of the 2500 rows in the file, it gave the same error. Interestingly the workstation cannot run the script with even just one row now.

Including `error_bad_lines=False`, `iterator=True`, `chunksize=`, `low_memory=False` have all not worked.

**What is causing this error? Why did it run just fine using a few rows, but now not even with one row?**

Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\script.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv("C:/Path/file.csv", encoding='latin-1' )
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 581, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1250, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 225, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1960, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 4
```

Here is the script:

```
# Import raw data
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Script.csv", encoding='latin-1' )

# Create array to track failed cases.
data['Test Case Failed']= ''
data = data.replace(np.nan,'')
data.insert(0, 'ID', range(0, len(data)))

# Testcase 1
data_1 = data[(data['FirstName'] == data['SRFirstName'])]
ids = data_1.index.tolist()
for i in ids:
  data.at[i,'Test Case Failed']+=', 1'

# There are 15 more test cases that preform similar tasks

# Total cases
failed = data[(data['Test Case Failed'] != '')]
passed = data[(data['Test Case Failed'] == '')]
failed['Test Case Failed'] =failed['Test Case Failed'].str[1:]
failed = failed[(failed['Test Case Failed'] != '')]

# Clean up
del failed["ID"]
del passed["ID"]

# Print results 
failed['Test Case Failed'].value_counts()
print("There was a total of",data.shape[0], "rows.", "There was" ,data.shape[0] - failed.shape[0], "rows passed and" ,failed.shape[0], "rows failed at least one test case")

# Drop unwanted columns 
redata = passed.drop(columns=['ConsCodeImpID', 'ImportID', 'Suff1', 'SRSuff2', 'Inactive', 
'AddrRegion','AddrImpID', 'AddrImpID', 'AddrImpID.2', 'AddrImpID.1', 'PhoneAddrImpID',
'PhoneAddrImpID.1', 'PhoneImpID', 'PhoneAddrImpID', 'PhoneImpID', 'PhoneType.1', 'DateTo', 
'SecondID', 'Test Case Failed', 'PhoneImpID.1'])

# Clean address  
redata['AddrLines'] = redata['AddrLines'].str.replace('Apartment ','Apt ',regex=True)
redata['AddrLines'] = redata['AddrLines'].str.replace('Apt\\.','Apt ',regex=True)
redata['AddrLines'] = redata['AddrLines'].str.replace('APT','Apt ',regex=True)
redata['AddrLines'] = redata['AddrLines'].str.replace('nApt','Apt ',regex=True)
#There's about 100 more rows of address clean up

# Output edited dropped columns  
redata.to_csv("C:/Users/cleandata.csv", index = False)
# Output failed rows
failed.to_csv("C:/Users/Failed.csv", index = False)
# Output passed rows 
passed.to_csv("C:/Users/Passed.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: can you share a small portion of `Script.csv` this error can be reproduced with (on the target workstation)?

Comment: Here you are: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yNFkjuo6XPXg_ED6V6RuCdjp7FSj3zHK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you confirm it gives the same error, including the line number (5)?

Comment: Could that error be misleading? All workstations are using the same script and same file.  Line 5 is ```pd.read_csv```

Comment: ah, right. My guess was that there might be interference between regional settings or default encoding and CSV separators. The file however is too large to look through entirely in a hex editor, so I read too much into the stacktrace. Can you reduce the file - the one line version with only a few columns would be much easier to check

Comment: If I remove columns from the file previously sent, couldn't I potentially remove the columns causing the issue for this workstation? Sorry if I'm not understanding.

Comment: yes, and it will be very helpful to know what columns are causing this problem. So, remove extra rows/columns until the problem is not reproducible, take a step back, and take a closer look at those row/columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workstation was corrupting the file, despite never opening it before running the script. I repaired the file and it worked. After reinstalling Excel, I no longer had to repair the file and could run the script as normal.

- Click File > Open.
- Click the location and folder that contains the corrupted workbook.
- In the Open dialog box, select the corrupted workbook.
- Click the arrow next to the Open button, and then click Open and
  Repair.
- Open and repair command
- To recover as much of the workbook data as possible, pick Repair.
- If Repair isn’t able to recover your data, pick Extract Data to
  extract values and formulas from the workbook.